# Avoid using field in group by

Tags: sql-server-2008

Im trying to do this sum based on the week but when I use the following code I obviously have to put week in my group by which means the output doesnt have one code for each week, it has numerous. Is there a way to not use week in the group by so it looks like

```
cde  channel  201305   201306   201307
rr1     2       0         0.6      1
```

where as now it looks like:

```
cde  channel  201305   201306   201307
rr1     2       0     null     null
rr1     2     null    0.6      null
rr1     2     null    null      1
```

This is my code

```
select cde,
case when week = '201305' then CAST((SUM(fin_acc_sum))AS FLOAT)/nullif(SUM(total),0) end as [201305],
case when week = '201306' then CAST((SUM(fin_acc_sum))AS FLOAT)/nullif(SUM(total),0) end as [201306],
case when week = '201307' then CAST((SUM(fin_acc_sum))AS FLOAT)/nullif(SUM(total),0) end as [201307],
channel
into #base2
from #acc_ref
group by cde,channel,week
order by channel,cde,week
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add MAX around each CASE expression and remove week from the GROUP BY

```
...
MAX
(case when week = '201305' then CAST((SUM(fin_acc_sum))AS FLOAT)/nullif(SUM(total),0) end
) as [201305],
...
group by cde,channel
order by cde,channel
```

You are effectively pivoting rows into columns so `week` does not have any meaning in the GROUP BY

Comment: Thanks. I know get message 'Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.'

Comment: @user1296762: Move the SUM outside the CAST